# Using sp_addlinkedserver to access a db on the same server - but with a different user

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use another database on the same server, but my current db-user has no access to the other one.
I tried to `sp_addlinkedserver`-link the server to itself, so I could use `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` to specify another user, but I get error messages for denied permission before I even get to the second part; I suspect because it is on the same server.

Here's what I came up with:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver
        @server= N'SameServer',
        @srvproduct= N'SQL Server';

exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
        @rmtsrvname= N'SameServer',
        @useself= N'FALSE',
        @rmtuser= N'AlternativeLogin',
        @rmtpassword= N'';
```

The error messages tell me that the user lacks permissions for the procedure `sp_MSaddserver_internal` (?), as well as `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin`

Ultimately, I'd also like to use an alias for the connection because SameServer.dbName will be confusing, and I've found answers for doing that, but obviously, since I haven't gotten that far I can't test how that goes.

Comment: "SameServer.dbName will be confusing" More confusing that using a linked server?  Any SQL developer with decent experience will understand what `SameServer.dbName` is doing.  Note that if it's on the same server than you can just use `dbName..{table}`

Comment: Sorry. Confusing as in: how would one know if I meant the linked connection or directly accessed the other table. Therefore I'd need an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can run sp_addlinkedserver, then you most likely already have the permissions needed to gain access to the other database.

If you have rights to run sp_addlinkedserver, then sp_addlinkedsrvlogin would require you to know the password of "AlternativeLogin" or it has no password, ergo you don't need a linked server

Both sp_addlinkedserver and sp_addlinkedsrvlogin require elevated rights that would not typically by delegated outside the sysadmin group

Do it properly: ask your sysadmin or DBA.

Comment: I have both logins (one has no password), but they can both only access one database, not the other. But I guess the elevated rights would be my breaking point here. To the sysadmin we go.
Thank you.